# Cookie Not Grabbing All Codes

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

On Page Variable =

```
$lgc_code = '1,2,3,15,23,30';
```

Cookie = 'lgc_cntl'

My cookie is housing logic codes for each user to determine what banners or icons should show based on previous web pages visited. I have written the following function:

```
    $lgc=$lgc_code;

    // check for variable for multiple codes
    $expEncArr = explode(",", $lgc);
    $results = count($expEncArr);

        if(isset($_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'])) {

            // read cookie
            $cookie_codes = $_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];

            // Build Array of cookie codes
            $expEncArr2 = explode(",", $cookie_codes);

            foreach($expEncArr as $l_code) {
                    if(in_array($l_code, $expEncArr2)) {

                        $lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];

                    } else {

                        $lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'].','.$l_code;

                    } // end array search statement

            // add campaign to cookie
            setcookie('lgc_cntl',$lgc_codes,time() + (86400 * 365), "/", ".oru.edu"); // 86400 = 1 day      

            } // end foreach statement

        } else {

            $lgc_codes = $lgc;

            // add campaign to cookie
            setcookie('lgc_cntl',$lgc_codes,time() + (86400 * 365), "/", ".oru.edu"); // 86400 = 1 day

        } // end isset(cookie) if / else statement
```

If there is no cookie set, the function works perfectly but if there is a cookie found it only adds the last variable in the array versus any codes not found in the cookie already.

The function should work as follows:

- Separate on-page variable into an array
- Check for the cookie
- Separate Cookie values into an array
- Compare the variables on page to values in cookie
- Add any on page variables not found in the cookie

It is working all the way through but when the cookie is set, it is only adding the last variable in the string even if none of the others are not located in the cookie array. What am I doing wrong or how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake - `$_COOKIE` is not affected by calling `setcookie`. This is because `$_COOKIE` is created at the beginning of the PHP script execution based on data sent *from* the browser, and `setcookie` sends data *to* the browser.

Consequently, each time you run this line:

```
$lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'].','.$l_code;
```

Your value of `$lgc_codes` is the cookie string originally sent by the browser plus exactly one extra code.

The solution is to instead use a local variable, such as `$new_cookie_value`, to build up the full string, and then call `setcookie` once:

```
 $new_cookie_value = $_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];

 foreach($expEncArr as $l_code) {
      // if statement removed to keep example brief
      // Add extra code to list
      $new_cookie_value = $new_cookie_value .','.$l_code;
 }
 // Now call setcookie once with the desired value
 setcookie('lgc_cntl',$new_cookie_value,time() + (86400 * 365), "/", ".oru.edu");
```

[Aside: Do not underestimate the value of good variable names. Your code would be much clearer if `$expEncArr` and `$expEncArr2` had longer names which described what the difference was between them. Similarly, `$lgc`, `$lgc_code`, `$lgc_codes`, etc.]

Comment: Your set up doesn't filter out the codes already in the cookie so it ends up with duplicates in the cookie. How can this be modified so that only codes NOT already in the cookie are added?

Comment: I solved it by simply moving the 'setcookie' command inside the foreach sequence. Not sure if this is the optimal method but it works.

Comment: @JonathanAnspaugh I removed the `if(in_array(...` line just to keep the example brief. This isn't supposed to be code for you to copy and paste, I expected you to learn the principle and apply it to your own code now and in future. The important point is not to keep reading from `$_COOKIE`, because nothing is going to change it on each loop. You definitely *do not* need `setcookie` inside the `foreach` loop - you're only setting one cookie, so only need to set it once.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is very muddled.  This is what should be in the first portion of your `if` block

```
// read cookie
$cookie_codes = $_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];

// Build Array of cookie codes
$expEncArr2 = explode(",", $cookie_codes);

$lgc_codes = $_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];

foreach ($expEncArr as $l_code)
{
    if (!in_array($l_code, $expEncArr2))
    {
        $lgc_codes .= ',' . $l_code;
    }
}

setcookie('lgc_cntl', $lgc_codes, time() + (86400 * 365), "/", ".oru.edu");
```